# My website address redirects to '/mail' automatically after mail server installation

Tags: email-server, mx-record, dns-zone, centos8, iredmail

I followed this instruction to setup a mail server on my VPS: https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/centos-8-iredmail-email-server
After installation completed successfully, when I try my website address(`sssss.com` for example), it automatically redirects to `sssss.com/mail` and shows up the email login page! So I can not rach the web sites first page.

The followings are my related files on my VPS.

var/named/fwd.sssss.com.db:

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN  SOA     ns1.sssss.com. root.sssss.com. (
                                              1490        ;Serial
                                              3600        ;Refresh
                                              1800        ;Retry
                                              604800      ;Expire
                                              86400       ;Minimum TTL
)

;Name Server Information
@       IN  NS      ns1.sssss.com.
@       IN  NS      ns2.sssss.com.



;IP address of Name Server
ns1       IN  A       94.130.98.33
ns2       IN  A       94.130.98.33
sssss.com.       IN  MX   10    mail.sssss.com.

;A - Record HostName To Ip Address
sssss.com.     IN  A       94.130.98.33
www             IN  A       94.130.98.33
mail            IN  A       94.130.98.33
@               IN  A       94.130.98.33

;CNAME record
ftp     IN CNAME        www.sssss.com.
```

var/named/sssss.com.rev:

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN  SOA     ns1.sssss.com. root.sssss.com. (
                                       1490        ;Serial
                                       3600        ;Refresh
                                       1800        ;Retry
                                       604800      ;Expire
                                       86400       ;Minimum TTL
)

;Name Server Information
@       IN  NS          ns1.sssss.com.
@       IN  NS          ns2.sssss.com.
ns1     IN  A           94.130.98.33
ns2     IN  A           94.130.98.33


;Reverse lookup for Name Server
33      IN  PTR         ns1.sssss.com.
33      IN  PTR         ns2.sssss.com.
33.98.130.94.in-addr.arpa    IN  PTR         ns1.sssss.com.
33.98.130.94.in-addr.arpa    IN  PTR         ns2.sssss.com.

;PTR Record IP address to HostName
33      IN  PTR         www.sssss.com.
33      IN  PTR         sssss.com.
33      IN  PTR         mail.sssss.com.
33.98.130.94.in-addr.arpa    IN  PTR         www.sssss.com.
33.98.130.94.in-addr.arpa    IN  PTR         sssss.com.
33.98.130.94.in-addr.arpa    IN  PTR         mail.sssss.com.
```

etc/named.conf:

```
//
// named.conf
//
// Provided by Red Hat bind package to configure the ISC BIND named(8) DNS
// server as a caching only nameserver (as a localhost DNS resolver only).
//
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
//

options {
        //listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; };
        //listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 94.130.98.33; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
        recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
        allow-query     { localhost; 94.130.98.33; };

        /*
         - If you are building an AUTHORITATIVE DNS server, do NOT enable recursion.
         - If you are building a RECURSIVE (caching) DNS server, you need to enable
           recursion.
         - If your recursive DNS server has a public IP address, you MUST enable access
           control to limit queries to your legitimate users. Failing to do so will
           cause your server to become part of large scale DNS amplification
           attacks. Implementing BCP38 within your network would greatly
           reduce such attack surface
        */
        recursion yes;

        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

        pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
        session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";

        /* https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/CryptoPolicy */
        include "/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/bind.config";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};
//forward zone
zone "sssss.com" IN {
        type master;
        file "fwd.sssss.com.db";
        allow-update { none; };
        allow-query  { any; };
};

//backward zone
zone "98.130.94.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "sssss.com.rev";
        allow-update { none; };
        allow-query  { any; };
};
```

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3:

```
# Generated by parse-kickstart
TYPE="Ethernet"
DEVICE="enp0s3"
UUID="467a30cc-f47a-4c63-a335-f8afab26f559"
ONBOOT="yes"
IPADDR0="94.130.98.33"
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
IPV6INIT="no"
DNS=94.130.98.33
```

etc/resolv.conf:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search sssss.com
nameserver 94.130.98.33
```

Nginx works on my server address: 94.130.98.33 but my domain doesn't work!

EDIT: This is the rewult of `dig @94.130.98.33 sssss.com any` (The real domain name is `sssss` instead of `sssss`:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.13-RedHat-9.11.13-5.el8_2 <<>> @94.130.98.33 sssss.com any
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 54410
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 4

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: c279563b1d3fe85ccebd7b085f4a20a5d456e6e90441bac5 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;sssss.com.                    IN      ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
sssss.com.             86400   IN      SOA     ns1.sssss.com. root.sssss.com. 1490 3600 1800 604800 86400
sssss.com.             86400   IN      NS      ns2.sssss.com.
sssss.com.             86400   IN      NS      ns1.sssss.com.
sssss.com.             86400   IN      MX      10 mail.sssss.com.
sssss.com.             86400   IN      A       94.130.98.33

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.sssss.com.         86400   IN      A       94.130.98.33
ns2.sssss.com.         86400   IN      A       94.130.98.33
mail.sssss.com.        86400   IN      A       94.130.98.33

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 94.130.98.33#53(94.130.98.33)
;; WHEN: Sat Aug 29 11:32:21 CEST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 229
```

Comment: DNS configuration is not relevant to HTTP redirects. Please add your web server configuration to the question.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen: Thank you, but I don't know which file(s) should I add to my question? My website is written by Angular + NodeJS.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen: I thought maybe I had a mistake in creatng MX record or in DNS related files.

Comment: When you installed iRedMail, it made changes to your web server configuration. Those changes cause the redirect you are seeing. In order to give advice, the web server configuration is needed so it can be fixed.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen: In which file can I find it?

Comment: Sorry but I am unable to help you. You need to learn some fundamental concepts in IT before you can operate mail servers. Those concepts cannot be taught in a site like Stack Exchange. You should hire a professional to help you if you want fixes right away.